# How to display the Top N metrics with Timelion? (Elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

I've read a few posts about people trying to display the Top N metrics relative to date histogram. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-line-chart-limit-number-of-lines-over-date-histogram/52700

The somewhat concensus is to use Timelion to refer to a prexisting query but I can't find an example of that. Can someone walk me through it?

For (imaginary) bonus points, my more specific question is: what are the top N splitted terms of the weekly average of the daily max of this metric?

To show I've tried but not necessarily helpful:

```
.es(index=<my index>,metric=max:process_duration,split=<term>.keyword:7,timefield=@timestamp).mvavg(8).label("$1", "^.* > <term>.keyword:(.+) > .*"  ).color('blue:green:yellow:red').title("Top <term> Duration").yaxis(label="<term> Duration (s)",color=white)
```